# How to restrict adding a same product once again in order line in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

In sale order after adding a product in order line then once again we can add same product .So I want to restrict it.If I will add same product it has to show warning you have already added same product.

Can anybody help me how can I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sql constraints:

In your product model add  below line.

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('constraint name', 'unique(field1,field2)', 'Warning msg'),
    ]
```

Hope it will help you.